# API Call in Android Studio using volley (JAVA)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am very new to this and just jumped straight into trying to make API calls. I am trying to retrieve information from rapidAPI for a simple project I am working on to view prices of stocks and so on. I am using the volley package from Android Studio to make my APIcalls to retrieve JSON and trying to put that into a textView. The way I imagine this to work is that I press a button and then once that is clicked, it runs the code to get the information and then shows the response in the textView. however, when the button is clicked, nothing happens. no error or response of any sort.

```
    private TextView mTextViewResult;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextViewResult= findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
        Button buttonParse= findViewById(R.id.button_parse);

        mQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        buttonParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                jsonParse();
            }
        });

    }
    private void jsonParse(){
      String url="https://apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com/market/get-quotes?region=CA&lang=en&symbols=VEQT.TO";
        JsonObjectRequest request= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray= response.getJSONArray("result");

                    JSONObject result=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    int marketPrice= result.getInt("regularMarketPrice");

                    mTextViewResult.setText(String.valueOf(marketPrice));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mTextViewResult.setText("" +error.toString());
            }


        }){
            @Override
            public Map<String,String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError{
                Map<String,String> params= new HashMap<>();
                params.put("x-rapidapi-host", "apidojo-yahoo-finance-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
                params.put("x-rapidapi-key", "APIKEY");
                return params;
            }
        };
        mQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted are you sure your `x-rapidapi-key` is `APIKEY`. Pretty sure that's the primary reason of your issue. Only after you put a valid API key in your request header, will your API call return a proper expected response.

You can read how to generate the rapidapi key from their [official docs here](https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys)

Currently the response you receive on api call using the wrong apikey is something like this:

```
{
   "message": "Key doesn't exists"
}
```

Now in your java code you are looking for a JSONArray based on the key "result", while the response currently only has "message" being returned. That's the reason nothing happens, you can try finding the value in response for message and get the error messages if you wish. Generate a valid rapidapi key and try again, Good luck!